# How can i create a Google type search functionality in (Sharepoint 2013)

Tags: 2013, search, enterprise-search

I have a list of Glossary terms with their respective descriptions in i-share 2013.  I want a similar google search functionality where you type in the term name and brings the matching results with respective descriptions.

How do I do that in SharePoint 2013?

Comment: Is that Sharepoint 2013 on Premise or Sharepoint Online? What is i-share?? You mean "similar google search functionality" as in you start typing and it brings the results right away? I'm pretty sure you can do that with a javascript that as soon as you start writing would be considered as doing a search per word, but that could be very taxing to the server as it's not Google.

Comment:  Welcome! Here are 3 tips to enhance your question so it gets the best response. ►1 : Add more tags then just 'search', people have favourite Tags they monitor closely. ►2 : You searched the web for an answer, show people the links to Blogs you tried but did not work for you. ►3 : And please use the StackOverflow Voting and Answer buttons, they are there to get you the best answer, now, and for your future questions. [See the StackOverflow Tour](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour) for all the details

Answer (score 0):

- Option 1 - Use REST API `http://server/_api/search/query` to return the results based on entered keyword (you can use more parameters to restrict your search to particular list / library)
- Option 2 - Configure search web part to return results from particular list / library. Use display template to configure the result look and feel. For input keyword, use OOTB search web part, apply css to have desired look.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! but can you clarify or provide more details.   I am not clear if 1st option is just to create a search not to retrieve the results.  and 2nd option will really help bringing the description of the glossary term.

Comment: First option is to get search results based on keyword entered using REST API. Using single HTML & CSS you can create the google search like text area n button. On button click event, call the REST API to return results. Results could be presented in any format as required.